# keypress/keyup is not working on chrome mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, mobile-browser

I have been using jquery in my web based Asp.net MVC application, and when i use chrome mobile to test my work i found that jquery's functions which are based upon keypress/keyup is not working.

I didn't know why it is not working on mobile browsers. It is working properly on desktop browsers.

Can anyone solve my problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of [keyup not working on Chrome on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974021/keyup-not-working-on-chrome-on-android)

Comment: Thank you @FedericoklezCulloca

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
    http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/8137/onkeyup-event-not-firing-in-firefox-and-chrome

The code:

```
<textarea name="textarea" id="txtComments" rows="3" onkeyup='return fnMaxLength(this,"5");' style="width: 940px" ></textarea>
```

function fnMaxLength(field, maxChars) {

```
if (field.value.length >= maxChars) { 

    var object = "-More than " + maxChars + " characters have been entered.";

    //errorAlert("error", "Maximum length error", object);

    alert(object);

    return false; 

}
```

}