# Angular 5 - preventDefault() not working on mobile chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive

I have this directive:

This directive should disable typing on input `type="number"`
after reaching max length (that passed as an input).

Because maxlength attribute doesn't work on `type="number"`.

```js
export class AIGMaxLengthDirectiveCO {
    constructor(private elm: ElementRef) { }
    @Input('aigmaxlengthCO') aigmaxlength: number;

    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
    handleKeyboardEvent(e: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 9 || e.keyCode === 46) {  //  Backspace\tab\delete
            return true;
        } else if (this.isTextSelected(e)) {
            return true;
        } else if ((e.target as HTMLInputElement).value.length >= this.aigmaxlength) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
    isTextSelected(e) {
        if (document.getSelection().toString() !== '') {
            return true;
        }
        const textbox = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
        const startIndex = textbox.selectionStart;
        const endIndex = textbox.selectionEnd;
        return endIndex - startIndex > 0;
    }
}
```

```html
      <input [aigmaxlengthCO]="9" class="aig-input aig-17 input-text padding-0" type="number" formControlName="id" [ngClass]="form.get('id').invalid && (form.get('id').touched|| validations) ? 'error' : ''"/>
```

As in the third `if` block you can see the
`return false` and the `preventDefault()`.

**my problem that is on *mobile* Chrome it just doesn't stop the event,
I can see that I enter the third "if" block, and should return false,
but it's not working.
On the desktop, all works fine**

Things I tried:

- changing `keydown` to `keypress`.
- changing `keydown` to `document:keydown`.

Comment: See here if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011740/event-preventdefault-not-working-for-android-chrome

Comment: @David thanks for the reply. but I need angular solution, not html and js.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be a better solution if you implement (change) evento on your input?
You could still pass itself for your method and check for its value.

```
<input [aigmaxlengthCO]="9" (change)="handleKeyboardEvent" class="aig-input aig-17 input-text padding-0" type="number" formControlName="id" [ngClass]="form.get('id').invalid && (form.get('id').touched|| validations) ? 'error' : ''"/>
```

and your method would be the same:

```
handleKeyboardEvent(e: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 9 || e.keyCode === 46) {  //  Backspace\tab\delete
            return true;
        } else if (this.isTextSelected(e)) {
            return true;
        } else if ((e.target as HTMLInputElement).value.length >= this.aigmaxlength) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The difference is that what I think is happening after some testing and googling is that chrome web browser for mobiles don't work well with keypress and keydown

Source:

- [keypress/keyup is not working on chrome mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668105/keypress-keyup-is-not-working-on-chrome-mobile-browser)
- https://github.com/substance/substance/issues/982
- https://therealmofcode.com/posts/2014/03/where-is-keypress-event-chrome-android.html

The last link offers another solution, but I think passing a directive for (change) would be enough :)

Comment: thank you for the links, but your solution doesn't work.
the change event not being fired (I tried to test it with regular function in regular component).